# Error displaying geotiff raster data on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, contour, geotiff

I hope someone can help me.  I am trying to place isolines with labels from a geotiff file onto a leaflet map.  The webpage https://geoexamples.com/d3-raster-tools-docs/plot/isolines.html is the example I am looking at, but the problem is that they perform this task on a non-moving leaflet map (no zoom feature).  I have found the page https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/ where he places JSON data over a leaflet map, but does not cover how to transform geotiff data.

I can get the leaflet map to work and zoomable the JSON data remaps correctly but the geotiff data, while it displays, is not remapping correctly in my code and I don't quite understand how to make the isolines resize correctly.  I thought it was taken care of with the svg.insert command but it doesn't.  I know I am missing a step somewhere but I'm not sure where.

It seems like I am trying to do two things that are not quite explained anywhere combined.  I eventually want to use the streamline code, too, which is why I am not using the XML code in the simple isolines code (and I need the labels).  I got that version to work fine.  I have also tried adding a canvas layer but that didn't work either, but perhaps I did something wrong with that.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions on this.  I think I have provided the necessary code and links to the files.

https://geoexamples.com/d3-raster-tools-docs/code_samples/tz850.tiff

https://geoexamples.com/d3-raster-tools-docs/code_samples/world-110m.json

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([-0.2858, 60.7868], 3);
mapLink =
  '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>';

// Add an SVG element to Leaflet’s overlay pane
var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
  g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

d3.request("http://geoexamples.com/d3-raster-tools-docs/code_samples/tz850.tiff")
  .responseType('arraybuffer')
  .get(function(tiffData) {
    d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-countries/master/data/countries.geojson", function(geoShape) {

      //  create a d3.geo.path to convert GeoJSON to SVG
      var transform = d3.geo.transform({
          point: projectPoint
        }),
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

      // create path elements for each of the features
      d3_features = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(geoShape.features)
        .enter().append("path");

      map.on("viewreset", reset);

      reset();

      // fit the SVG element to leaflet's map layer
      function reset() {
        bounds = path.bounds(geoShape);

        var topLeft = bounds[0],
          bottomRight = bounds[1];

        svg.attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
          .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
          .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
          .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

        g.attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," +
          -topLeft[1] + ")");

        // initialize the path data 
        d3_features.attr("d", path)
          .style("fill-opacity", 0.7)
          .attr('fill', 'blue');

      }

      // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
      function projectPoint(x, y) {
        var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
        this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
      }
      var tiff = GeoTIFF.parse(tiffData.response);
      var image = tiff.getImage();
      var rasters = image.readRasters();
      var tiepoint = image.getTiePoints()[0];
      var pixelScale = image.getFileDirectory().ModelPixelScale;
      var geoTransform = [tiepoint.x, pixelScale[0], 0, tiepoint.y, 0, -1 * pixelScale[1]];

      var zData = new Array(image.getHeight());
      for (var j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j++) {
        zData[j] = new Array(image.getWidth());
        for (var i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i++) {
          zData[j][i] = rasters[0][i + j * image.getWidth()];
        }
      }

      var invGeoTransform = [-geoTransform[0] / geoTransform[1], 1 / geoTransform[1], 0, -geoTransform[3] / geoTransform[5], 0, 1 / geoTransform[5]];

      var intervalsZ = [1400, 1420, 1440, 1460, 1480, 1500, 1520, 1540];
      var linesZ = rastertools.isolines(zData, invGeoTransform, intervalsZ);
      var colorScale = d3.scaleSequential(d3.interpolateYlOrRd)
        .domain([1400, 1540]);
      linesZ.features.forEach(function(d, i) {
        svg.insert("path", ".streamline")
          .datum(d)
          .attr("d", path)
          .style("stroke", colorScale(intervalsZ[i]))
          .style("stroke-width", "2px")
          .style("fill", "None");
      });
    })
  })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/raw/bef48021e38a77a520109d2088bff9eb/98a0b74b01109afae76d28bc27c4d1dbc7a87da8/geotiff.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/raw/bef48021e38a77a520109d2088bff9eb/98a0b74b01109afae76d28bc27c4d1dbc7a87da8/d3-marching-squares.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/raw/bef48021e38a77a520109d2088bff9eb/98a0b74b01109afae76d28bc27c4d1dbc7a87da8/path-properties.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d19vzq90twjlae.cloudfront.net/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I should have added links to the js libraries. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-geotiff@0.2.0/leaflet-geotiff.min.js  https://github.com/rveciana/raster-marching-squares/blob/master/build/d3-marching-squares.min.js

Comment: You'll get better answers if you turn your code into a [mre], see also [ask]!

Comment: Hi Ruben.  Thank you for your reply.  I believe the code I included was about as minimum as I could make it without losing any pertinent information needed to reproduce the issue or determine where the error is.  I apologize if I am wrong on this... I am new to stack overflow and just hope someone could copy/paste my code and let me know where the error is.

Comment: I tried to turn your code into a runnable snippet. I've replaced the local files `geotiff.js` and `raster-marching-squares.js` with online ones, can you check if the version is correct? I've replaced `worldmap-110m.json` with an online version. You're loading two versions of d3 - that can't be right. Remove either one of them, or the package will not work. Can you try and make the snippet do what you see locally? Same error messages, etc

Comment: Hi again Ruben.  I fixed the code to run in the snippet (thank you for setting that up!).  The raster-marching-squares.js was actually d3-marching-squares.js.  I had to replace the worldmap with a different version since my version was in lat/lon but the world-110m.json is in point projection... so the projectPoint transformation was failing.  If I take out either d3 version the code fails, so I left them in.  I created my local json map at this site : https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/  I think that answers everything you asked.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: I see lines on your plot, but they move around when zooming. Can you describe or sketch the desired outcome?

Comment: The static plot, which I am trying to duplicate on the movable Leaflet plot, should look like the one displayed on this page http://geoexamples.com/d3-raster-tools-docs/plot/isolines.html.  This is what I am trying to do eventually... plot the isolines with labels and streamlines, but this was a good starting point.

Comment: Getting the points to not move on zoom is one thing, getting them in the right position is another. Can you describe what the correct behaviour should be without zooming?

Comment: When the code snippet is run the isolines should appear over the region at the center of the plot (or very close to).  The blue background map (from the json file) is plotted correctly, but the data from the tiff is not being converted correctly.  The plot region will be a limited area of coverage (as shown in the link in my previous post).  This coverage region should not change when a zoom is performed.  Right now the plotting region is shifted to the upper left corner instead of over the Saudi Arabia region, and will stay there as the image is zoomed in/out.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm guessing nobody was able to find a solution to this issue or have moved onto other issues.  Thanks to any/all who tried to help!